# Requests to my bank website are not handled

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I would like to scrape data from my bank account, for my personal use. 
The script works for another pages but I do no receive any data when I request it.
I have tried with PhantomJs and CasperJs.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://google.com', function() {
     this.echo("title:" + this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('https://www.creditmutuel.fr/cma/fr/banques/particuliers/index.html', function() {
    this.echo("then title: " + this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('https://yahoo.com', function() {
    this.echo("then title: " + this.getTitle());
});


casper.run();
```

The output of this script:

```
title:Google
then title: Google
then title: Yahoo France
```

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have and what is shown when you register to the `page.error` event? Have you tried to run it with `--ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true`?

Comment: The version is 1.9.7

Comment: I do not have any error, but I do not receive the http status code with onResourceReceived (handled one time), res.status is null.

Comment: Why does the 2nd line also print `Google`? Shouldn't it print `CreditMutuel etc.`?

Comment: Thank you! `--ssl-protocol=any`  fixed the problem

Comment: Can you try it only with the ssl-protocol option? So we can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Yes, there is no need of `ignore-ssl-errors` in order to make the script working

Comment: @Halcyon that was my problem, and I think also a kind of bug, because the second request displays data from the first.

Comment: https://github.com/airportyh/testem/issues/419